# Association between an ordinal Likert variable and a nominal variable

Tags: chi-squared-test, spss, ordinal-data, likert, order-statistics

I have responses from a 7 point Likert semantic differential scale -let's say from 'Completely Agree' at one end to 'Completely Disagree' to the other- and a nominal/semi-ordinal age groups variable containing three values -'less than 18', '18-35', 'more than 35'. What test do you think is the appropriate and the best for this scenario? Pearson Chi-Square and Linear-by-Linear association both report as significant, but I'm not sure if these tests are the most appropriate for this type of association. I'm using SPSS.

Comment: Is your Likert response variable from a single Likert item, or a scale composed of several items?

Comment: Your age variable is actually *interval-censored*. The categories are certainly ordered; I am curious why you call it "semi ordinal" -- what's "semi" about it?